# jquery selector result is prevObject: e.fn.e.init[3] how do I get an element from that

Tags: jquery

I have a selector `$('.element')` is returning `prevObject: e.fn.e.init[3]`. I looked into the results and the first object there is what I need. 2 questions here. What is `prevObject`? Also how can I select from the result the first object. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to reproduce this, so we can see what's going on. Post a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To access the first element, simply use `[0]` or `.get(0)`

`prevObject` is the result of the previous jQuery function call if the calls were chained together.  It's what allows the `.end()` call to pop the jQuery chain back to a prior state.

Comment: Thank you very much. All the info needed in a short time. Thanks again.